# Multiple LIKE clauses in Laravel Eloquent

Tags: sql, laravel, eloquent

I currently have this code in my controller:

```
$JobSuggestions = DB::table('jobs')
->orwhere('skillsetNeeded','like','%Accounting%')
->orwhere('skillsetNeeded','like','%Web Design%')->get();
```

The above code works, but what I want is to get "Accounting" and "Web Design" from an array, and just loop through that array so that the query is dynamic instead of hard coded on the controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
$array = ['web design', 'accounting']; 
$result = DB::table('jobs')
   ->where(function ($query) use($array) {
     foreach($array as $key) {
        $query->orWhere('skillsetNeeded', 'LIKE', "%$key%")
     }
   })
  ->get();
```

Comment: You you need to pass here 2 variable `$accounting` and `$design` as an array.

Comment: Hi there! Thanks for the comment. But accounting, and webdesign exists in just one array; like:  $array = ['web design', 'accounting'];

Comment: I tried this:         

$JobSuggestions = DB::table('jobs')
            ->where(function ($JobSuggestions) use($array) {
                for ($i = 0; $i < count($array); $i++){
                    $JobSuggestions->orWhere('skillsetNeeded', 'like',  '%' . $array[$i] .'%');
                }
            })->get();

But I'm only getting one result which should show 2

Comment: Opps, then it should where, not orWhere `$JobSuggestions->where('skillsetNeeded'....` try and let me know

Comment: It currently gets one row from the Database instead of 2, which is very weird. :/

Comment: What do you get at `$JobSuggestions = DB::table('jobs')
->whereIn('skillsetNeeded','like','%' . $accounting[$i] .'%')->get(); `???

Comment: Your code was actually working. I was using an old migration file, so the dataset that I was querying wasnt working, but it worked when I migrated to the new data