# Laravel orWhereIn and orWhereIn and so on

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

To be honest I rly do not know how to describe my query problem, hope example will clear things up:

I've got simple query:

```
return $query->whereHas('categories', function ($q) use ($ids) {
    $q->whereIn('category_id', $ids);
}, '=', count($ids));
```

which returns records that match array of categories ids. To present this better right now we've got such condition

```
getRecordsThatMatchThisCondition(id1 && id2 && id3... and so on).
```

What I want is to achieve such comparasion

```
getRecordsThatMatchThisCondition((id1.1 || id1.2 || id1.3) && (id2.1 || id2.2) ... and so on.)
```

I've couldn't find any help with this problem so far. Even naming such query would be helpfull. My table is simple PIVOT

```
id    record_id    category_id
------------------------------------
1         1            35
2         2            41
3         2            74
4         3            74
5         3            40
6         4            40
```

Summarizing my problem with words:

I do not have record relation to parent_category of selected category... Right now I need to display all records that match multiple categories.

Visualising problem:

```
Record is assigned to categories like this:

35
 └40
 └41 ☑
36
 └74 ☑
```

By providing id 35 and 36, record should be found! By providing 40, 74 should **NOT** be found...

Hope I've described my problem well enough.

Comment: Why do you want to do this kind of condition?

Comment: @MrEduar Well... Long story short. I've had a brilliant idea, not to save all relations to categories. In other way, I am saving only lowest category on category tree selected by user. However now I need, to create "mixed-category" which displays all records that match **ALL** categories provided by user. However simple whereIn is not enought, because if record belongs to (look at tree I've provided in question) category_id: 41, and mixed-category is bind to 35, I won't find such record. To find this record I would have to create mixed-category that is connected to every child node of tree...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't query with `whereIn` method like this, but can use a foreach loop,  like this :

```
return $query->whereHas('categories', function ($q) use ($ids) {
    foreach($ids as $key => $value) {
        $q->orWhere('category_id', $value)
     }
}, '=', count($ids));
```

Or, with `for` loop :

```
return $query->whereHas('categories', function ($q) use ($ids) {
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($ids); $i++){
                $q->orWhere('category_id', $ids[$i]);
             }
}, '=', count($ids));
```

Comment: Something like that https://stackoverflow.com/a/63198246/4575350